The smallest almost sure covering of the real line using iid Gaussian random variables
I was working on a problem in machine learning when this thought crossed my mind regarding the difference between sampling from an RV and the range of an RV. I'm going to use the standard Normal distribution as a concrete example.
Let $Z_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ be an infinite sequence of iid random variables.
Let $S_n:= \{Z_i: i\leq n\}$ be a truncation of this sequence.
We know the range of each $Z_i$ is $\mathbb{R}$, a continuous 1-d space. However, each $S_n$ is only a finite number of points. Hence $\text{Leb}(S_n) = 0\;\forall n$.
This seems to imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \text{Leb}(S_n) = 0$ so that no matter how many samples we take from $Z_i$ we will never cover the entire number line, not even a tiny fraction of it.
Now, let's do a twist on this.
Let us define an interval covering from $S_n$
$$S_n(\delta) := \bigcup_1^n [Z_i-\delta/2, Z_i+\delta/2]\;\; \delta>0$$
And we ask the same question: Will $S_n(\delta)$ eventually cover the entire real line?
In this case the answer seems to be yes.
Let $L_n(\delta) := \text{Leb}(S_n(\delta))$. By the definition of $S_n(\delta)$, $L_n(\delta)$ forms a monotonically increasing, unbounded sequence in $n$.
For any fixed $\lambda > 0$, we can define an event $E_n(\lambda):= \mathbb{1}_{> \lambda}(L_n(\delta))$. We know that $P(E_n)$ is also a monotonically increasing sequence bouned from above by 1. Therefore, by Borel-Cantelli, $P(\lim \sup E_n)=1$ and so the $L_n$ will exceed $\lambda$ infinitely often for any $\lambda > 0$. By monotonicity, this implies $\lim_{n \to \infty} L_n(\delta) = \infty\;\forall \delta > 0$
What is confusing is that this seems to hold for any $\delta > 0$ yet we know that
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} L_n(\delta) = \infty \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{\delta \to 0} L_n(\delta) = 0$$
So, it seems that there is a nonuniform convergence occurring. Am I missing somethig?

What would you consider to be your one question that you want answered here?

How do you apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma in your claim ?

Everything is correct in your math, as far as I can tell. One thing to keep in mind is that you will cover the range [-4,4] fairly quickly, but everything outside of that will take values of $n$ that are humongous.

@ThànhNguyễn the events here are the Lebesgue measure exceeding a given bound. The probability incrases with time, so it will exceed the bound infinitely often (in fact, it will always exceed it once it crosses the threshold),

@BrianMoehring - apologies if my post was a bit rambling. I want to know why the two limits at the bottom don't commute (assuming my math isn't crap)
